# Adding CSS to change font size

Tags: html, css

On this page: https://www.nycofficesuites.com/new/offices/, I want to change the font size on red bar across the top (where it says "Office Space").   I've entered this code but it's not working.

```
.page-title h1 {
font-size: 35px !important;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't update the existing rule, your new rule will need to appear after the existing rule as they are both marked as "!important".

The existing rule is showing in "custom.css":

```
.page-title h1 {
    font-size: 46px !important;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In custom.css you have,

```
.page-title h1 {
  font-size: 46px !important;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

Either edit that file or add/load your overriding css after custom.css (order of load matters, the last one is considered).

Side note: Try to avoid using `!important` as much as you can.

Answer (score 0):

If this is something you are just messing with you can declare it inline.

```
<h1 style="font-size: 35px !important;">Office Space</h1>
```

Or

```
.header {
font-size:35px;
font-weight:bold;
font-family: 'Pontano Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
font: inherit;
vertical-align: baseline;
}

<span class="header">Office Space</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just figured this out, thanks for your help everyone.  The person who wrote the theme put this in a file called custom.css.php.  So this was overriding the place where I was entering CSS.  (This is a Wordpress site.)